# PIC SPI configuration questions

Tags: pic, spi

I have some questions related to SPIxCON registers of SPI. I use PIC18F26K83.
1) There is a SPIxTCNTH: SPI TRANSFER COUNTER MSB REGISTER. And I can set first 3 bits on it which counters the bits to be transmitted. And according to datasheet it is writable bit. According to the datasheet it counts bits that will be transmitted then why is it writable? Do I need to write it according to bits that I will send? Or is it there to inform user.

2) There is SPIxTWIDTH: SPI TRANSFER WIDTH REGISTER. In case of BMODE=1, it is 
Size (in bits) of each transfer counted by the transfer counter
I will be sending values such as 1.1  or 2.3 to DAC. In this case what should I set it to? Is there a standart value for this register?

3) I couldn't get what are FIFO registers are for according to datasheet we cannot control them by software. Isn't it like a buffer? So If I am writing to transmit register faster than transmission speed, the transmit data will be put into the FIFO. And one by one they will be transmitted. Am I correct? I do not need to anything rather than writing to the transmit buffer.

4) I read but could not understand the polarity bits in SPIxCON1. Is it okay if I do not touch these bits in the control register? I do not want to mess up.

5) How can I select slaves? There is a SSET (Slave select enable bit) in the SPIxCON2 register. I can make it 1, but then how can I select the slave?

Thank you for your answers. I am a newbie. Sorry for the simple and maybe non sense questions. Or I can simply show my configuration code, but I believe it would be harder to analyse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  The transfer counter (when in use) is written to with the number of bytes, or partial bytes, to send or receive (depending on mode).  So you'd set it, if you are using it (BMODE=0 or TXR=0) to the number of bytes that you are expecting to send or receive.

2) You'd need to look at your binary representation of those numbers to see how many bits you'd be sending in each case.  Standard value is a full byte.

3) the FIFOs are hidden elements, writing to the SPIxTXB or reading from the SPIxRXB registers accesses the respective FIFO.  the FIFOs are only two bytes deeps so you'd still need to check for overrun if you are sending fast TXWE bit (iirc) but if you have lots of data to transfer fast I'd recommend using DMA to do the transfer then you'd just be setting it up and letting it go and can do other things until it is finished.

4) I think the polarity bits just set the line level during idle state to either high or low.  It should be set the same for everyone (masters and slaves).

5) If you only have one slave you can tie that line to the slaves enable line.  If you have more than one slave you'll need to set up a gpio line for each and (for each one) OR the signals together and attach the OR output to the slave enable (if it is active low, which it usually is).  Make sure only one slave is active at a time.  Doing a daisy chain of slaves can be done as well.  I haven't worked with that kind of setup.

Comment: In case you you haven't perused it, the datasheet is a good source for answers. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001943A.pdf